# Gunicorn settings for virtualenvwrapper

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a test site which made using `Django` and `virtualenvwrapper`. I want to use nginx for requests.I used Taskbuster's tutorial. So my project layer is similar as below :

```
--abctasarim                       **main folder
--manage.py                        **django manage file
----/yogavidya                     ** project folder
----/yogavidya/wsgi.py             **wsgi file
----/yogavidya/settings/base.py    ***settings
```

I prepared a script to use with gunicorn. I addressed virtualenv to `virtualenvwrapper` envs

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="yogavidya"                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim     # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=ytsejam                                        # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=webdata                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yogavidya.settings.base           # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=yogavidya.wsgi                     # WSGI module name (*)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/bin/activate
#export /home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/bin/postactivate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/gunicorn  \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE \
  --pythonpath $DJANGODIR \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE yogavidya.wsgi:application
```

When I try to run it , I am getting an error for my service file :

```
...
ImportError: No module named ' '
...
```

How can I fix my script to serve the site correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenvwrapper` is supposed to be what you use in development.  You want to deploy using the package that `virtualenvwrapper` is built on—the `virtualenv` package.  The best suggestion I have for you for how to make this work would be to try the steps that you would normally use to start your `virtualenvwrapper` environment, namely sourcing the shell script and then using `workon`:

```
NAME="yogavidya"                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim     # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=ytsejam                                        # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=webdata                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yogavidya.settings.base           # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=yogavidya.wsgi                     # WSGI module name (*)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGO_DIR
source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon yv_dev
```

You should also just try invoking `gunicorn` from the command line after `activat`ing your virtualenv.

---

Here’s how you can do it with `virtualenv`:

```
cd /home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim 
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv .
. bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install gunicorn
```

gunicorn script:

```
NAME="yogavidya"                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim     # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=ytsejam                                        # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=webdata                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)

cd $DJANGO_DIR
. bin/activate

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec /home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/bin/gunicorn  \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE yogavidya.wsgi:application
```

Comment: basically , I was just losing time trying to use virtualenvwrapper , I understand that ?

Comment: Was that a question?

Comment: Yes but to make myself sure, I dont need it , I just need to setup application for production only with virtualenv and deploy it . I can make gunicorn work from command line, but I cant make it work from script , always saying "ImportError: No module named ' '
"

Comment: Yup, confirmed.  You don’t need `virtualenvwrapper` when deploying.

Comment: ok for the last question , which is the correct way to address a setting file ? DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yogavidya.settings.base  , it cant find the module with this one. or this means that I cant enter virtualenv?

Comment: I usually set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in manage.py.  If you already have it set there, you don’t need to include it in the gunicorn startup script.

Comment: I can make it work with gunicorn in virtualenv , but when I start it with script :ImportError: No module named 'gunicorn'
this is how I edited it but still does not work https://dpaste.de/QRKG . I think I need to rewrite my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130888/discussion-between-2ps-and-ytsejam).

Comment: thanks for help again and again , you saved my days. although mistake was my script was not accepting the line seperating "\" and was not accepting options.